# How to skip first element in the range in a For Each loop statement?

Tags: excel, vba

The thing I want to do is relatively simple. I have a data set which I filtered based on a criteria, hence hiding some of the rows in my worksheet. I set a range for my filtered data which should only go through cells that are visible with sample code.

```
With MyDataWorksheet.AutoFilter.Range
     On Error Resume Next
     Set AutoFilterRange = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
     On Error GoTo 0
End With
```

Now I would like to loop through all my data in the AutoFilterRange variable which should have captured all rows that are visible. I Loop through them doing something like this.

```
Sub aSub()

Dim DR As Range
For Each DR In AutoFilterRange
    'Do something here
Next DR

End Sub
```

I use this for each loop to do stuff with the visible rows, however I would like to just skip the first element in the data range as this element row number contains my header names. I thought doing something like this would help solve my problem, but all it does is go to the next hidden row element right after the header row element.

```
For Each DR In AutoFilterRange.Offset(1,0)
    'Do something here
Next DR
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this

```
With MyDataWorksheet
    If .AutoFilterMode Then
        With .AutoFilter.Range
            Set AutoFilterRange = .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        End With
    End If
End With
```

In your code you don't show what AutoFilterRange would be if AutoFilter is not On, so I also skip that part.

Comment: I think this would do the job. I only use the AutoFilterRange variable when I have to deal with data that is filtered based on a few criteria. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

You could add an if statement and a "flag".

```
Sub aSub()

Dim DR As Range
Dim flag as Boolean
flag = false
For Each DR In AutoFilterRange
    If flag = true Then
        'Do something here
    End If
    flag = true
Next DR

End Sub
```

This will skip the first iteration due to flag is false, then I set it to true and it will `do something` on all the other iterations.

Comment: Probably not but it's the only method I can give you from my phone. I think you could `rng = AutoFilterRange` and perhaps manipulate it from there

Comment: Alright! I will try looking further into your suggestion as well. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You could change the range in order to not use the first row:

```
Set AutoFilterRange = Range(Range("A2"), Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Cells
```