# Find names in Word document then input the names into Excel cells except the first found

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

The code finds and extracts the counterparts names/surnames from the beginning of the Word document, then puts these names into consecutive cells in Excel, for example "A12", "A13" and "A14".

The Word document looks like:
[image]

The target Workbook looks like:
[image]

The names/surnames were changed/mixed and in ID numbers some digits where changed. No matching personal data is revealed in screenshots provided.

There is one thing I don't know how to achieve:

**The full name of the first counterparty found, in the example below it's "Jan STANEK" is not supposed to be written into the worksheet.**

The end effect of the macro should be:

1. "Jan STANEK" is not written anywhere in the worksheet, It is extracted while searching through the document but skipped during input to the worksheet phase,
2. "Michal Lukasz ROESLER" is written into cell "A12",
3. "Katarzyna Paula STANISZKIS-KRAWCZYK" is written into cell "A13",
4. "Tomasz Leon Bogdan WISNIAK-STRYCZEWSKI" is written into cell "A14" and so on.

```
Sub FindNamesByRonRosenfeldWithInput()
    Dim WordApp As Word.Application
    Dim WordDoc As Word.Document
    Dim ExcelApp As Excel.Application
    Dim MySheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim Para As Word.Paragraph
    Dim Rng As Word.Range
    Dim pStart As Long
    Dim pEnd As Long
    Dim Length As Long
    Dim TextToFind1 As String
    Dim TextToFind2 As String
    Dim firstName As String
    Dim fullName As Word.Range
    Dim startPos As Long
    Dim endPos As Long
    Dim x As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Assigning object variables
    Set WordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    Set ExcelApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    Set WordDoc = WordApp.ActiveDocument
    Set MySheet = Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    'Set MySheet = ExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    Set Rng = WordApp.ActiveDocument.Content
    TextToFind1 = "REGON 364061169, NIP 951-24-09-783,"
    TextToFind2 = "- ad."
    x = 11

    'InStr function returns a Variant (Long) specifying the position of the first occurrence of one string within another.
    startPos = InStr(1, Rng, TextToFind1) - 1    'here we get 1421, we're looking 4 "TextToFind1"
    endPos = InStr(1, Rng, TextToFind2) - 1      'here we get 2497, we're looking 4 "- ad."
    If startPos = 0 Or endPos = 0 Then Exit Sub
    Rng.SetRange Start:=startPos, End:=endPos
    Debug.Print Rng.Paragraphs.Count

    If startPos = 0 Or endPos = 0 Then
        MsgBox ("Client's names were not found!")
    Else
        'The full name of the first counterparty found, is not supposed to be written into the worksheet.
        'It's not important and I just want to skip it.
        'Macro needs to start entering names from the full name of the second counterparty that's found,
        'in a way that: 2nd counterparty's full name is written into cell "A12", 3rd counterparty's full name is written into cell "A13",
        'and 4th counterparty's full name is written into cell "A14" and so on.
        For Each Para In Rng.Paragraphs
            firstName = Trim$(Para.Range.Words(3))
            'Debug.Print firstName
            pStart = InStr(Para, ".") + 1       'here we get 3
            Length = InStr(Para, ",") - pStart  'here we get 14/25/39 - 3
            Debug.Print Trim(Mid(Para, pStart, Length))
            x = x + 1
            Cells(x, 1).Value = Trim(Mid(Para, pStart, Length))
        Next Para
    End If
End Sub
```

My idea is, maybe these `Para` iterations are numbered in any way? Can I check if they are numbered?

In this part of the code, close to the end of it:

```
For Each Para In Rng.Paragraphs
    firstName = Trim$(Para.Range.Words(3))
    'Debug.Print firstName
    pStart = InStr(Para, ".") + 1       'here we get 3
    Length = InStr(Para, ",") - pStart  'here we get 14/25/39 - 3
    Debug.Print Trim(Mid(Para, pStart, Length))
    x = x + 1
    Cells(x, 1).Value = Trim(Mid(Para, pStart, Length))
Next Para
```

Can we write something like:

```
If para iteration is larger than 1 than
    x = x + 1
Cells(x, 1).Value = Trim(Mid(Para, pStart, Length))
```

This way the first counterparty's full name would be skipped and next counterparty's full names would be written into the desired cells.
Would something like that work?

Comment: Is that personal information of actual Polish citizens on that screenshot?

Comment: @GSerg
No, it's not. The names/surnames were changed/mixed and in ID numbers some digits where changed. No matching personal data is revealed in screenshots provided. Thank you for bringing my attention into this subject.

Comment: If the name you are looking for is always behind a number of the for X. then Word' wildcard search is probably the simplest option

Comment: The code that extracts the names/surnames is working fine and does it's thing. What I need now, is to exclude the first person's full name from being written into the worksheet cell, because it's not important for me and I don't have an empty cell to put it. @Freeflow  If your comment does this, please provide the code as an answer. I'm just a beginner in VBA and need some time to integrate this code into the worksheet and test it on my worksheet and documents. The plain 2 line comment doesn't help much. The names are found - it's the part of the code that populates worksheet I need help with.

Comment: If you have the range for the name then just use a movestartuntil with cset set as a space character.

Comment: By the first name I didn't mean JOHN or ADAM or MICHAEL. I meant the name of the first counterparty, the one that's found in The paragraph starting "1. Jan STANEK...". Maybe I need to rephrase the question. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I'm expecting some slight modification to my code, somewhere close to the end of it, probably after the line ```Debug.Print Trim(Mid(Para, pStart, Length))``` resulting with first counterparty's full name being skipped (not written into the sheet) and the 2nd counterparty's full name being written into cell "A12", 3rd counterparty's full name being written into cell "A13" and 4th counterparty's full name being written into cell "A14" and so on.

Comment: I've added some ideas, to the post, how this problem could be solved, which I simply don't know how to implement.

Comment: Can the VBA flag in conjunction with the IF statement be used to skip the first counterparty's full name from being written into the sheet? I've seen it here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53775671/how-to-skip-first-element-in-the-range-in-a-for-each-loop-statement   in the second answer, that wasn't marked as the right solution, but gained 2 upvotes.

Comment: Have you tried what you suggest at the end of the question? Something along those lines would be possible. Or declare a variable of type `Boolean` and assign it `True`.  Inside the loop place an `If` that checks the value of the variable; when it's `False` the content is executed. Just after `End If`, before the loop repeats, assign `False` to the variable. The first time, what's in the `If` is skipped, after that it is executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@michalroesler  The code below will search a range in a Word document and return a scripting.dictionary of names where the name conforms to the rules
1. the number is at the start of a line 
2. the name is terminated by a comma.

This appears to be what is used in your document.

Once you have the list it is easy to delete the first name, or even extract it if you need to use it elsewhere.

In the the test sub you will see how to iterate though all the items in the scripting dictionary.  From this it should be easy for you to deduce how to populate your excel file.

2020-02-04 Edit based on comments made by the OP I've updated the code below to do the full task.

My reasons for updating the code is that I've always felt that SO should try and educate at the same time as providing answers.

The code provided by the OP shows a lot issues that can be neatly avoided by separating out the individual tasks.  Namely

1. Identify if a search range exists in the source document
2. Collect a list of names conforming to specific layout rules
3. Process the names in some way (in this case that's just deleting the first name)
4. Transfer the names to an excel worksheet in a vertical column starting at a named cell..

The OP has tried to do this in a single sub which means you end up with a large sub.

The updated code I've provided takes the OP original code re-sequences the provided code, comments out parts of the original code that are no longer required, and replaces the commented out code by smaller functions whose purpose is focused on a single task.  Arguably, there are a few places where even smaller functions could be used.

The code has been inspected by the fantastic rubber duck addin for VBA (which is there the '@Ignore comments come from).  The code inspections from RubberDuck are a fantastic aid to writing bug free code.

I've tested it on a small word document I created with names that aligned with the rules I deduced above.

I've tried to show good practices I've learned in the past year or so from my googling of VBA issues.

1. Variables are declared at the nearest safe place to where they are first used.
   This is because it makes the job of refactoring code with RubberDuck much, much easier
2. Longer, more meaningful names.
   I don't know what the OP means by variable x, does anyone else?
3. the code does things in the appropriate environment.
   • Data is extracted from Word
   • The extracted data is processed in VBA
   • the processed data is written back to  Excel
   Because in this instance the task, as explained by the OP, is amenable to being processed in this manner.

I hope the updated code is more satisfactory to the OP.

```
Public Sub FindNamesByRonRosenfeldWithInput()

    Const FirstName                                     As Long = 1

    'It would probably be better to padd TextToFInd1 & 2 as parameters to this function
    'Dim TextToFind1 As String
    Const TextToFind1                                   As String = "REGON 364061169, NIP 951-24-09-783,"

    'Dim TextToFind2 As String
    Const TextToFind2                                   As String = "- ad."

    Dim WordApp As Word.Application
    Set WordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")

    Dim WordDoc As Word.Document
    Set WordDoc = WordApp.ActiveDocument

    'Dim Rng As Word.Range - used more expressive name
    'Set Rng = WordApp.ActiveDocument.Content
    Dim myNamesSearchRangeInWord As Word.Range
    Set myNamesSearchRangeInWord = getSearchRangeInDocument(WordDoc, TextToFind1, TextToFind2)
    myNamesSearchRangeInWord.Select
    'If startPos = 0 Or endPos = 0 Then
    If myNamesSearchRangeInWord Is Nothing Then

        '@Ignore FunctionReturnValueDiscarded
        MsgBox ("Client's names were not found!")
        Exit Sub

    End If

    Dim myNames As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set myNames = GetNumberedNames(myNamesSearchRangeInWord)
    '@Ignore VariableNotUsed
    Dim myNamesStr As Variant
    myNamesStr = myNames.Items
    'Delete the first name that we found from the list of names
    myNames.Remove FirstName
    myNamesStr = myNames.Items
    'Dim firstName As String
    'Dim fullName As Word.Range

    ' The fourth line below shows you are running in Excel so the next two lines are not needed
    ' because you already have the excel application object.
    ' Dim ExcelApp As Excel.Application
    ' Set ExcelApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    Dim mySheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Set mySheet = Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    'Dim Para As Word.Paragraph

    'Dim pStart As Long
    'Dim pEnd As Long
    'Dim Length As Long
    'Dim startPos As Long
    'Dim endPos As Long
    'Dim x As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Assigning object variables
    'x = 11
    'InStr function returns a Variant (Long) specifying the position of the first occurrence of one string within another.
    'startPos = InStr(1, Rng, TextToFind1) - 1    'here we get 1421, we're looking 4 "TextToFind1"
    'endPos = InStr(1, Rng, TextToFind2) - 1      'here we get 2497, we're looking 4 "- ad."
    'If startPos = 0 Or endPos = 0 Then Exit Sub
    'Rng.SetRange Start:=startPos, End:=endPos
    'Debug.Print Rng.Paragraphs.Count


    'Else
        'The full name of the first counterparty found, is not supposed to be written into the worksheet.
        'It's not important and I just want to skip it.
        'Macro needs to start entering names from the full name of the second counterparty that's found,
        'in a way that: 2nd counterparty's full name is written into cell "A12", 3rd counterparty's full name is written into cell "A13",
        'and 4th counterparty's full name is written into cell "A14" and so on.

'        For Each Para In Rng.Paragraphs
'            firstName = Trim$(Para.Range.Words(3))
'            'Debug.Print firstName
'            pStart = InStr(Para, ".") + 1       'here we get 3
'            Length = InStr(Para, ",") - pStart  'here we get 14/25/39 - 3
'            Debug.Print Trim(Mid(Para, pStart, Length))
'            x = x + 1
'            Cells(x, 1).Value = Trim(Mid(Para, pStart, Length))
'        Next Para
'    End If

    'transfer the remaining names to the excel worksheet in a single action
    Dim myitems As Variant
    myitems = myNames.Items
    Dim myXlRange As Excel.Range
    Set myXlRange = mySheet.Range("A13")
    Set myXlRange = myXlRange.Resize(myNames.Count, 1)
    myXlRange.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(myNames.Items)

End Sub


Public Function getSearchRangeInDocument(ByVal ipDoc As Word.Document, ByVal ipStartText As String, ByVal ipEndText As String) As Word.Range

    With ipDoc.StoryRanges.Item(wdMainTextStory)

        With .Find

            .ClearFormatting
            .Text = ipStartText
            .Replacement.Text = vbNullString
            .MatchWildcards = False
            .Wrap = wdFindStop

            If Not .Execute(Replace:=wdReplaceNone) Then Exit Function

        End With

        Dim mySearchRange As Word.Range
        Set mySearchRange = .Duplicate
        .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
        '@Ignore FunctionReturnValueDiscarded
        .MoveStart Count:=1

        If Not .Find.Execute(findtext:=ipEndText) Then Exit Function

        mySearchRange.End = .End

    End With

    Set getSearchRangeInDocument = mySearchRange

End Function


Public Function GetNumberedNames(ByVal ipRange As Word.Range) As Scripting.Dictionary

    Dim myEndOfSearchRange As Long
    myEndOfSearchRange = ipRange.Document.StoryRanges.Item(wdMainTextStory).End
    Dim myNames As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set myNames = New Scripting.Dictionary

    With ipRange

        With .Find

            .ClearFormatting
            .Text = "(<)([0-9]{1,})(.)( {1,})([!,]{1,})"
            .MatchWildcards = True
            .Wrap = wdFindStop

        End With

        Do While .Find.Execute

            ' If it is likely that the loop will take a long time then put a DoEvents Statement here
            myNames.Add getNumberFromRange(.Duplicate), getNameFromRange(.Duplicate)
            .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
            '@Ignore FunctionReturnValueDiscarded
            .MoveStart Count:=1
            .End = myEndOfSearchRange

        Loop

    End With

    Set GetNumberedNames = myNames

End Function


Public Function getNumberFromRange(ByVal ipRange As Word.Range) As Long

    '@Ignore FunctionReturnValueDiscarded
    ipRange.MoveStartUntil cset:="0123456789"
    '@Ignore FunctionReturnValueDiscarded
    ipRange.MoveEndUntil cset:=".", Count:=wdBackward
    '@Ignore FunctionReturnValueDiscarded
    ipRange.MoveEnd Count:=-1
    getNumberFromRange = CLng(Trim$(ipRange.Text))

End Function


Public Function getNameFromRange(ByVal ipRange As Word.Range) As String

    '@Ignore FunctionReturnValueDiscarded
    ipRange.MoveStartUntil cset:="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    getNameFromRange = Trim$(ipRange.Text)

End Function
```

Comment: Hello @Freeflow and thank you for your answer. Nonetheless, I need to stress that the Code I provided works well, It's finding the names I need, it extracts them, it strips them of the ```number.space``` in the beginning and it populates the worksheet into the right cells. All I ask is a simple modification to my code, with a simple goal of skipping the first counterparty's full name, while populating the worksheet and starting entering names beginning from the 2nd counterparty's full name. And you provided completely new subroutine + 3 public functions. That's not what I've expected :-(

Comment: I'm expecting some slight modification to my code, somewhere close to the end of it, probably after the line ```Debug.Print Trim(Mid(Para, pStart, Length))``` resulting with first counterparty's full name being skipped (not written into the sheet) and the 2nd counterparty's full name being written into cell "A12", 3rd counterparty's full name being written into cell "A13" and 4th counterparty's full name being written into cell "A14" and so on.

Comment: @michalroesler I've updated my answer to give complete code together with an explanation of why I felt it reasonable to not just provide a fix to the code you posted.

Comment: thank you @Freeflow for updating your answer.
I need some time to digest your code. If there's something I don't understand I hope you'll explain it here in some brief comment.

Comment: No problem.. Ask away.  But first put the cursor on the keyword you don't understand and press F1 to get the MS help page.